# subtraction and multiplication column wise

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, numpy

i need to do subtraction and multiplication columns. as per the below format.

df1

```
 A  B   C   D   E
10  11  13  12  15
11  13  10  15  13
```

there can be 'n' number of columns.

```
formula - subtraction: 
column 1 - column B, them col B - col C then col C - col D and so on. 

formula - Multiplication: 
row1 multiply by row2
```

expected output:

```
                   A      B   C    D    E
SUBTRACTION       -1     -2   1   -3    15
MULTIPLCATION    -11     -26  10 -45    195
```

Comment: Do you only want the first row to be subtracted?

Comment: yes like, for A = 10 - 11 = -1, B = 11-13 = -2, for C = 13-12 = 1, for D = 12 -15 = -3 and for E = 15 as it is. and so on ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want the first row to be subtracted and then multiplied by row 2:

```
arr = df.values
df
    A   B   C   D   E
0   10  11  13  12  15
1   11  13  10  15  13

df.iloc[0, :-1] = arr[0, :-1] - arr[0, 1:]
df

     A  B   C   D   E
0   -1  -2  1   -3  15
1   11  13  10  15  13
```

The `.values` will convert the Data Frame into a numpy array. If you don't do this, then pandas will only subtract corresponding columns.

```
df.iloc[1,:] = arr[0] * arr[1]
df
     A  B   C    D   E
0   -1  -2  1   -3   15
1   -11 -26 10  -45  195
```

Then change the index:

```
df.index = ['SUBTRACTION', 'MULTIPLCATION']
df

                 A   B   C  D   E
SUBTRACTION      -1 -2   1  -3  15
MULTIPLCATION   -11 -26  10 -45 195
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `indexing` and then `mul` and `sub` as:

```
df.iloc[0,:-1] = df.iloc[0,:-1].sub(df.iloc[0,1:].to_numpy())
df.iloc[1,:] = df.iloc[0,:].mul(df.iloc[1,:])
df.index = ['SUBTRACTION', 'MULTIPLCATION']

print(df)
                A   B   C   D    E
SUBTRACTION    -1  -2   1  -3   15
MULTIPLCATION -11 -26  10 -45  195
```

Answer (score 0):

Or why not:

```
>>> df.iloc[0] = df.iloc[0].sub(df.iloc[0].shift(-1)).fillna(df.iloc[0])
>>> df.iloc[1] = df.iloc[0].mul(df.iloc[1])
>>> df
      A     B     C     D      E
0  -1.0  -2.0   1.0  -3.0   15.0
1 -11.0 -26.0  10.0 -45.0  195.0
>>>
```